# Take _stock quantity form another db Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I would need to show the "Stock Quantity" on another woocomerce site where both have the same sku.

then recall the quantities via snipped, the databases are separate

```
I tried with the recall but the productid is not right
function leggi_stock_da_altro_sito($atts) {
    global $post;

    // Connetti al database dell'altro sito WooCommerce
    $database_host = 'localhost'; // Inserisci l'host del database
    $database_name = 'sito2'; // Inserisci il nome del database
    $database_user = '-----------'; // Inserisci il nome utente del database
    $database_password = '-----------------'; // Inserisci la password del database

    $connessione = new mysqli($database_host, $database_user, $database_password, $database_name);

    // Controlla se la connessione è riuscita
    if ($connessione->connect_error) {
        return 'Errore di connessione al database.';
    }

    // Ottieni lo SKU del prodotto dalla pagina del prodotto corrente
    $sku = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sku', true);

    // Esegui una query per leggere lo stock
    $query = "SELECT stock_quantity FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_title = %s"; // Sostituisci "wp_posts" con il prefisso corretto delle tabelle nel database dell'altro sito
    $query = $connessione->prepare($query);
    $query->bind_param('s', $sku);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($stock_quantity);
    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();

    $connessione->close();

    // Formatta il risultato con la frase desiderata
    $output = '<p>Ci sono ' . $stock_quantity . ' prodotti.</p>';

    // Restituisci il risultato formattato
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('leggi_stock', 'leggi_stock_da_altro_sito');
```